# To show that $A_4$ is solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I need to show that $A_4$ is solvable.
From what i know the definition of solvable expects to give some chain of subgroups such that each subgroup in the chain is normal to the one in which it is contained and also the quotient group is abelian.

So I tried constructing such a chain but I was not able to

Comment: So what are the subgroups of $A_4$ and which of those are normal?

Answer (score 3):

$A_4$ has a normal abelian subgroup $V=\{ id, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23) \}.$ Then we have a normal series $A_4 \vartriangleright V \vartriangleright E$. Here $|V|=4$. Hence, $|A_4/V|=3$ and thus $A_4/V$ is abelian.

Comment: Thanks. For $S_4$ I will have $A_4$ and then the chain of $A_4$ right ?

Comment: Yes, @SMath, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

$|A_4|=4!/2=2\cdot 3\cdot 2=2^2 \cdot 3$. In general if $|G|=2^2\cdot 3$ we have a solvable group.

Actually we can prove something stronger!

> Let $p,q$ be two distinct primes. Every group $G$ of order $|G|=p^2q$ is solvable.

I will assume standard facts. If you want me to, I can edit my post and prove them later.

1. **If $N\lhd G$ is solvable and $G/N$ is solvable, $G$ is solvable**
2. **If $p$ is prime and $|G|=p$ or $|G|=p^2$, $G$ is abelian.**

With this in mind we know by the Sylow theorem that $n_p| p^2q$. Because $n_p\equiv 1 \mod p$, we can only have $n_p\in\{1,q\}$. Similarly, $n_q\in\{1,p,p^2\}$. If it happens that $n_p=1$, then $P\in \text{Syl}_p(G)$ is such that $P\lhd G$. Because $|P|=p^2$, $P$ is abelian (first fact) and hence solvable ($1\lhd G$ and $G/\{1_G\}$ is abelian ). Furthermore $|G/P|=q$, hence abelian ans solvable, so $G$ is solvable by our first fact.

Similarly, if $n_q=1$, $G$ is solvable. Let us suppouse by way of contradiction that $n_p=q$. We know $q\equiv 1 \mod p$. This means $q=1+pz$.

If $n_q=p^2$ or $n_q=p$, we have $p^2\equiv 1 \mod q$. So $q|p-1$ or $q|p+1$. If $q|p-1$, we have $q<p$, but $q=1+pz>p$, contradiction! On the other hand, if $q|p+1$ we have $q\leq p+1$ and also $q=1+pz>p$, so $q=p+1$ Because they have different parity, we must have $p=2$ and $q=3$.

In this case the only possibility for this not to be a solvable group is when $n_3\in\{2,4\}$, but $2\not \equiv 1 \mod 3$ so $n_3=4$ and $n_2\in\{3\}$. As $n_2=4$, we have $\{Q_1,Q_2,Q_3,Q_4\}=\text{Syl}_2(G)$. If $Q_i\not=Q_j$, we have

$$Q_i\cap Q_j\subset Q_i$$

If $|Q_i\cap Q_j|=|Q_j|=3$, this is absurd, so we must have them intercepting each other only trivially. In other words, there are $8$ elements of order $3$ in $G$. There are also $3$ elements of order $2$ or $4$.

$$G=\{\text{$8$ elements of order $3$}\}\dot{\cup} \{\text{$3$ elements of order $2$ or $4$}\}\dot{\cup}\{1_G\}$$
So sets in $\text{Syl}_2(G)$ are in $G\cap \{\text{$8$ elements of order $3$}\}^C$. But there are only $4$ elements left. So $n_2=1$. Contradiction! So it must be solvable.